# strange java script behaviour

Tags: javascript, weblogic

There is a js file where i have:

```
    var formString="<form action=\"" + location + "\" method=\"POST\" 
id=\"submitform\">";
```

somehow in browser when i look on the js file i see

```
    var formString="<form action=https://www.acceptance.test.br/submission/eforms/js/\""
 + location + "\" method=\"POST\" id=\"submitform\">";
```

so it is added to the source code js the server url.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it - the second version is what you see when the file is opened in a browser (by viewing its source)?

Comment: Why do you think it's JavaScript behavior? If the JavaScript source is showing up malformed, then it would seem to be whatever is delivering it.

Comment: the java script source code deployed  is the first part of the code...when click view source i see the second...and when i click submit goes to the wrong place ...

Comment: still is possible to somehow the source code of the original js file to be modified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your serverside code is not set up correctly and injects stuff into the stream.

You probably need to split you action so the auto insertion stuff does not effect it.

```
var formString="<form act" + "ion=\"" + location + "\" method=\"POST\" id=\"submitform\">";
```

Comment: What framework [or proxy] are you using? Seems like it [or some proxy] injects the current path to the page into the action so it will point to the correct location.

Answer (score -1):

Your page will work just the same even if you don't use any quotes. People will gasp at your brashness for not using them but it is perfectly fine. Paul Irish says so.

```
var formString="<form action=https://www.acceptance.test.br/submission/eforms/js/"+location+" method=POST id=submitform >";
```

Comment: The poster does NOT want that url there [https://....] , that is being added by something else.

Comment: try overwriting the location variable.